# Connection lost after sudo reboot in vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I have started using Vagrant. I have some issues in restarting my VM.
My Vagrantfile is:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config
config.vm.box = "precise32"
config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"
```

I open SSH by Vagrant SSH. Now if i give `"sudo reboot"` the connection to the VM is closed. I get the following:

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ sudo reboot
vagrant@precise32:~$
Broadcast message from vagrant@precise32
    (/dev/pts/0) at 9:43 ...

The system is going down for reboot NOW!
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed by remote host.
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

How to solve this? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run `sudo reboot`, it reboots the vagrant VM, as a part of the reboot process it'll kill all daemons and processes. Of course the sshd will be stopped or killed, as a result the connection to it (I mean `vagrant ssh`) will be lost.

Once the vagrant VM is up and running again, you can `vagrant ssh` to it again. Use `vagrant status` to check VM status.

The vagrant way of restarting a box is:

1. `Ctrl`+`d` to exit the SSH connection
2. `vagrant reload`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. When I rebooted, I couldn't log back in. I tried shutting down instead. That seemed to work.

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ sudo shutdown -h now
vagrant@precise32:~$ 
Broadcast message from vagrant@precise32
    (/dev/pts/0) at 5:16 ...

The system is going down for halt NOW!

vagrant@precise32:~$ exit
logout
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
foo$ vagrant status
Current machine states:

default                   poweroff (virtualbox)

The VM is powered off. To restart the VM, simply run `vagrant up`
foo$ vagrant up
```